# vuetify tabs component doesnt work correctly with flex animation

Tags: vue.js, tabs, flexbox, vuetify.js

I'm trying to get the v-tabs to work with my expand menu.
Basically when I click the toggle open, the right side menu will slide out, and inside this menu I want to use the tabs component from vuetify.
It doesn't seem to work, when clicking on the tabs, it's jumping all over the places.
It starts to work correctly when I resize the window manually. Any help please?

Here's the codepen

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/WmKQLp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a [Navigation Drawer](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers) without any custom styling needed... (Vuetify has built in components for what you're trying to accomplish)..

Here is a 'quick and dirty' pseudo example showing how you can accomplish this:

[Codepen Example can be found here.](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/mojrZM?editors=1010) ***updated with resizing ability***

---

---

**EDIT:**
If you did want to use your custom CSS, you will need to add an additional custom CSS class - this is happening because of the `translate`, among other Vuetify styles conflicting with your custom CSS...

[As outlined here](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/BbPQwG), add this class: (***I highly advise against doing this***)

```
.v-tabs__container {
  transform: translateX(0px)!important;
}
```

---

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer app right width="550" v-model="navigation.shown">
      <v-toolbar color="primary">
        <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
          <span>t a</span><span class="font-weight-light"> B S </span>
        </v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-tabs>
        <v-tab v-for="n in 3" :key="n">
          Item {{ n }}
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item v-for="n in 3" :key="n">
          <v-card flat>
            <v-card-text>Content for tab {{ n }} would go here</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-tab-item>
      </v-tabs>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-btn @click="navigation.shown = !navigation.shown">Toggle {{ direction }}</v-btn>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

---

**JS/Vue**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      navigation: {
        shown: false,
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    direction() {
      return this.navigation.shown === false ? "Open" : "Closed"
    }
  },
});
```

---

---

**EDIT: *(with resizing ability)***

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer 
      ref="drawer" 
      app 
      right 
      :width="navigation.width" 
      v-model="navigation.shown"
    >
      <v-toolbar color="primary">
        <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
          <span>t a</span><span class="font-weight-light"> b s </span>
        </v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-tabs>
        <v-tab v-for="n in 3" :key="n">
          Item {{ n }}
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item v-for="n in 3" :key="n">
          <v-card flat>
            <v-card-text>Content for tab {{ n }} would go here</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-tab-item>
      </v-tabs>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-btn @click="navigation.shown = !navigation.shown">Toggle {{ direction }}</v-btn>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS/Vue:**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      navigation: {
        shown: false,
        width: 550,
        borderSize: 3
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    direction() {
      return this.navigation.shown === false ? "Open" : "Closed";
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setBorderWidth() {
      let i = this.$refs.drawer.$el.querySelector(
        ".v-navigation-drawer__border"
      );
      i.style.width = this.navigation.borderSize + "px";
      i.style.cursor = "ew-resize";
    },
    setEvents() {
      const minSize = this.navigation.borderSize;
      const el = this.$refs.drawer.$el;
      const drawerBorder = el.querySelector(".v-navigation-drawer__border");
      const vm = this;
      const direction = el.classList.contains("v-navigation-drawer--right")
        ? "right"
        : "left";

      function resize(e) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "ew-resize";
        let f = direction === "right"
          ? document.body.scrollWidth - e.clientX
          : e.clientX;
        el.style.width = parseInt(f) + "px";
      }

      drawerBorder.addEventListener(
        "mousedown",
        function(e) {
          if (e.offsetX < minSize) {
            el.style.transition = "initial";
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
          }
        },
        false
      );

      document.addEventListener(
        "mouseup",
        function() {
          el.style.transition = "";
          vm.navigation.width = el.style.width;
          document.body.style.cursor = "";
          document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
        },
        false
      );
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setBorderWidth();
    this.setEvents();
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply, the reason why I made my own component instead of using the drawer was, so that user can drag and resize the drawer

Comment: no problem! [Check out this Codepen again](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/mojrZM) - I added resizing.. although, it feels a little laggy, its the best I could do lol.. I coded it so it works whether the Navigation Drawer is on the right or left..

Comment: Edit: I refined the CodePen (thanks to some help on this site) - the resize now works flawlessly.

Comment: No problem. I learned a ton doing this since I didn't know how to already, and I couldn't put it down lol